# How to clear toast messages in primeng?

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using Angular8 and Primeng-8.1.1 version with Growl.

When there are more than one toast messages, screen looks very unclear because of multiple toast messages. I want to remove all the previously opened toast messages. Right now, I am using the below code as per primeng documentation. But it is not clearing the old toast messages.

```
this.messageService.clear();
this.messageService.add({
    severity: "success",
    summary: "Success Message",
    detail: "Success Message"
});
```

Comment: are the toast messages you're adding all generated from the same component? The `messageService` dependency you're injecting might only act on messages it's created within it's component.

Comment: Yes, it's part of the same component. All the toast messages are generated after success or error callback.

Comment: can you post your component code and template code?

Comment: @Bugbeeb : Thanks for the help. After deep diving, I got the solution. In the mentioned version of primeng, they use [Growl](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-6.1.6/#/growl) , it's deprecated and implementation of clear is not there. Posting my solution in answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging into the library code, I am able to find the solution.
This version of Primeng doesn't have the implementation of `clear()`.

`MessageService` has exposed `clearObserver` Observable. I have subscribed to it and assigned the `value` input of the component to blank array value.

**Template** :

```
<p-growl #toast [(value)]="msgs" life="10000"></p-growl>
```

**Component** :

```
msgs = [];
@ViewChild('toast', {static: false}) toast: Growl;
...
this.messageService.clearObserver.subscribe(() => {
     this.toast.value = [];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been raised on [gitHub](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/6606).

I would like to recommend using `Toast` instead of `Growl`, As `Growl` has been deprecated. (Check proof [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/pull/6615#issuecomment-428899719)).

Change your `HTML` code as follows

```
<p-toast position="top-left"></p-toast>
```

Now use your same `clear` function by Primeng

```
this.messageService.clear();
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am planning to upgrade from `Growl` to `Toast`.